# Use of smallserial gives error with PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I know the very basics of databases. I worked in the past with MySQL and recently switched to PostgreSQL (9.1) with PostGIS 2.0.1.

At the moment I'm designing a new database and I use the tool pgModeler for that. In MySQL I could use autoincrement for my primary keys, but PostgreSQL doesn't have that. Some searching showed me that I should use serial instead.
There are some small lookup tables in my design which have a smallint as primary key. So I switched them to smallserial, which is an option in pgModeler.
Now I'm trying to execute my query and it returns with the error:
ERROR: type "smallserial" does not exist

According to the [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-numeric.html) I see now that smallserial is not listed in table 8.2 but later on in the document (8.1.4) it is mentioned. Is this an small error in the documentation or am I missing something like some setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Smallserial has been introduced in core with [Postgres 9.2](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/release-9-2.html). In earlier version you could emulate it as it is only a short form. [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) of 9.2 gives a hint for it